# remove special characters from twitter trends

Tags: php, twitter

I need to remove special characters from twitter trends. Because the trends are used to form a url like `http://example.com/trends/trending-topic`.

If there is any special characters like **GÃ¤vle** , it will form ugly url. how can i remove those characters. Is there any list of allowed characters in trends?

Answer (score 0):

This is a double-edged sword.

You can use [`iconv()`](http://php.net/function.iconv) with the `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` feature to try and convert a UTF-8 string into a lesser character set, like US-ASCII.  The `//TRANSLIT` flag will convert any character that can be transformed into something sensical in the destination character set.  `//IGNORE` will prevent iconv from stopping when there's an error in the transliteration or the original encoding.

Be warned that characters that can't be transliterated will be dropped.  The closer your target charset can represent characters from the source, the better.  For example, many European languages can be transliterated over to US-ASCII without a problem, but trying to port over something like Cyrillic or something from the Asian continent is going to be a trainwreck.  This is where the double-edged sword comes in.  Encoding UTF in URLs may be visually ugly, but it's the most likely thing to work out for you long term.